# Retrieve data on basis of OnItemClickListner of listview generated from sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my app I am saving data into **SQLite** and showing in **listview** but later I want to retrieve the specific data on the basis of **onitemClickListner** of listview into the next activity in an **edittext**.  but I am unable to do that. How to generate a select query for getting data on basis of id?

my databasehelper class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Constants for Database name, table name, and column names
public static final String DB_NAME = "NamesDB";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "names";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_STATUS = "status";


//Constructor
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

//creating the database
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
            + "(" + COLUMN_ID +
            " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME +
            " VARCHAR, " + COLUMN_STATUS +
            " TINYINT);";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}


   public boolean addName(String name, int status) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_STATUS, status);


    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
    return true;
}
```

this is how I am saving data to sqlite

```
private NameAdapter nameAdapter;
//saving the name to local storage
private void saveNameToLocalStorage(String name, int status) {
    editTextName.setText("");
    db.addName(name, status);
    Name n = new Name(name, status);
    names.add(n);
    refreshList();
}
```

loading data to listview

```
private DatabaseHelper db;

private void loadNames() {
    names.clear();
    Cursor cursor = db.getNames();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Name name = new Name(
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME)),
                    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_STATUS))
            );
            names.add(name);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    nameAdapter = new NameAdapter(this, R.layout.names, names);
    listViewNames.setAdapter(nameAdapter);
}
```

it is showing data in listview

[image: data is loading in listview]

I am getting the id of the clicked item of the listview and sending it to next activity where I want to run a query and get the data of specific id but I am unable to do it.

```
listViewNames.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int id, long l) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, id+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Second.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your NameAdapter should have this method :

```
public Name getItem(int position) {
    return yourItems.get(position);
}
```

Then use your adapter to get the item by position:

```
listViewNames.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Name yourObject = nameAdapter.getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, yourObject+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Second.class);
            intent.putExtra("yourObject", yourObject);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

if you want to pass your object as Extra , it should implements Serializable or Parcelable.

**UPDATE**

Select method:

```
public Cursor getNames(int id){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT id, name, status FROM names where id = " + id, null);
return c;
}
```

Comment: I did that but it is returning me this value on listview item click "com.example.dzone.sync_sqlit.Name@43a10d3"

Comment: yes, because your are displaying your object, what do you want to display?

Comment: I want to display the name in the row where I click e.g  if a click on row 1 it will display me all the data of that row even in toast. is it possible if I upload code to onedrive and give you I think I'm not able to explain

Comment: Use , yourObject.getStatus() or any method  from your object Name

Comment: thanks bro for helping me and sharing knowledge and not acting like other fools who just degrade other rather than helping

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve name from you listitem and query the DB. add list item onclick. and use position to retrieve from adapter the name and after query db. result from db add as extra to intent and open new activity

Comment: I am getting the position of list item and sending to new activity but I want that query which will retrieve select the name on basis of id? can you provide that query to me?

Comment: @BilalSabir then you need to store id of row where you've insert your data/object. For example you add member id to your Name object and after you've inserted the name into db update your object with received id then on click item extract by position your object abd from object get id and pass through intent to new activity